# How to setup an empty password for a MySQL connection pool in glassfish 4 from the GUI?

Tags: passwords, connection-pooling, glassfish-4

Im being unable to set an empty password for a MySQL connection pool from the GUI in glassfish 4. In previous versions of glassfish it used to work by simply putting "()" without the quotes. It doesnt work anymore for me in glassfish 4.

By the way, I've been googling my issue with any luck.

Does anyone know what is the proper way to do it in glassfish 4?

Thanks in advance for you support

Regards

Comment: Have just run into the same problem

Comment: @Juan you have to accept the answer from Full-Fledged. It is perfect and it is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I did to fix this was to manually in /glassfish/domains/(yourDomainName)/domain.xml add the following property to the connection pool:

```
 <property name="password" value=""></property>
```

Remember to restart Glassfish after the change has been made.