# Am I missing a step in generating entity classes from a darby database using Netbeans, or is there an error with my Glassfish server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, netbeans, glassfish, database-connectivity

I am trying to run a simple Java EE application using NetBeans, Darby and Glassfish. The application will not run as the Glass fish server encounters an error during the initial stages of deployment:

> Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/projectpool__pm

The project builds fine.

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BdViMpiT) of the output to the NetBeans logs generated when implementing a clean build. Everything seems to work OK bar some issue with optional Eclipse config files.

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Kv87jw8E) of the output to the NetBeans logs generated when I try and run the application using Netbeans.

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BEsmkF0g) of the output to the Glass Fish logs generated when I try and run the application through NetBebeans.

The steps I followed to generate the entity classes included:

1. I created a Darby database and ensured it was connected.
2. I created a table in the database with some attributes, no data.
3. I went to the *Project-ejb* section of my application and generated entity classes by selecting *New* > *New Entity classes from database*.
4. When generating the classes I selected *Add a new data source*.
5. I selected the database I had created.

Following these steps generated the appropriate entity classes. Have I left out a step? Do I need to manually create a pool or is that done automatically when I completed steps 3, 4 and 5?

**I am unable to add a connection pool manually to the GlassFish server using the web portal.**

Pastebin of Glassfish logs on initialing the server: https://pastebin.com/F7eYYwy1 .

Comment: learn this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223003/entity-class-from-database-error-invalid-resource-pm/43224327#43224327 i think you have a problem with your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use glassfish server it is no longer supported by Oracle and it has bugs. Oracle left the glassfish project as an opensource project and it did not get the support required to sustain it. Try [Payara](https://www.payara.fish/). It is a well-supported fork of glassfish that I found to work quite well.